# 'Yeah but it's a dry heat' - reference to another film?

Tags: aliens

In Aliens when the marines first encounter the aliens, they head into the 'nest' and one of them says 'it's hot in here' and Hudson (Bill Paxton) says 'Yeah, but it's a dry heat'.

This line has always made me think that he is paying homage to another film or production.

Am I right or am I reading too much into the way he delivers the line?

Comment: In the biography of Vince Lombardi starring Ernest Borgnine (Portrait in Granite: The Vince Lombardi Story ), I recall Vince's character describing Green Bay winters to his wife Sarah: "But it's a dry cold." [Later, his wife retorts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tbd5-CM6pyU): "Good it's such a dry cold." Hearing that line many years ago, for the first time and not long after moving from Rouen-Noranda, Quebec, to Southern Ontario, was very memorable.

Comment: I always thought that was a weird line, with all the water dripping around him because of the apparent humidity. (But it was still funny!)

Comment: ["a bonfire's a dry heat"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcAq6fRADzI&t=3m40s)

Comment: RIP Bill Paxton (1955-2017)

Comment: "Cool Runnings" had "It's not the heat, it's the humidity", which also occurred in "Mr. Moto in Danger Island".

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's an old joke/cliche dating back many years but it's not movie related

> In Arizona, Texas and other parts of the west, the temperature often averages over 100 degrees during the summer. “But it’s a dry heat!” is the clichéd response that some natives give, explaining that it’s more tolerable without humidity. **“The thermometer frequently registers 120 in the shade, but it’s a dry heat**, and one doesn’t notice it at all” was cited in print in 1910 to jokingly describe the heat in Southern California.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/its_110_degrees_but_its_a_dry_heat_texas_heat_joke) with other references</sup>

Comment: I knew it was referring to something and it's no surprise that old jokes from the west of America don't really translate all that well to rainy old England !

Comment: This answer makes it seem like the phrase is *completely* a joke, and only used in that sense. It's not. Dry heat IS more tolerable than the same temperature in humid weather, and people still use it without making any kind of joke.

Comment: @sgroves Is 100% correct. 90° F in 100% relative humidity in the modern swamp of D.C. is almost unbearable, while 90° F in 10% RH in the modern desert that is LA is a pleasant afternoon.

Comment: It's not just that a dry heat is more comfortable, it can be survivable when the same temperature at high humidity would kill you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index#Table_of_values

Comment: When I (from NYC) went to college (near LA), I was shocked to discover on several occasions that the temperatures were in the 95-100 degree range—it didn’t feel *even remotely* that hot to me, since temperatures that high in (far more humid) NYC are vastly more unpleasant than the same temperatures in southern California.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a joke it is, really. 100 degrees in the Nevada desert is nothing like a high-humidity heat wave in the upper Midwest.

Comment: I live in AZ and I have been in the SouthEast in the midst of summer. I can tell you there is a significant difference. 120 degrees in Phx in the summer feels hot, yes, but you don't necessarily sweat like you would at 90 degrees in Georgia or South Carolina... The southeast is stickier than the south-west and it is far less comfortable.

Comment: It's a joke when the actual temperature gets high enough. A dry 250° (~120° C) is still going to kill you, and 120°/49° is going to be hugely uncomfortable for anyone who didn't grow up in that kind of weather no matter how low the humidity.

Comment: @1006a: I've been in surface temperatures as high as 150° F on tarmac in the summer sun, and there's an *enormous* difference between those temperatures in nice, dry Tucson, and the same temperatures in Doha, a couple miles off the Persian gulf, with humidity 20-30% higher than Tucson. I don't think there's anywhere on the planet, even with man-made pavement, that gets hot enough to kill you if you're properly hydrated and in decent condition, but you stay cooler in dry air than damp air for sure.

Comment: @MichaelS "I don't think there's anywhere on the planet" But the movie doesn't take place on this planet ;-). I'm not disagreeing with the idea that humidity affects how we feel heat; but taken to extremes, this truism can be a joke. "Oh, no, the super-villain has locked us in a walk-in kiln! It heats up to 2000 degrees!!!" "Yeah, but it's a dry heat."

Comment: @1006a : I regularly go into a dry 210F (100C) for pleasure (sauna). http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-10912578 suggests some people go into 160C for a few minutes.

Comment: With high humidity, its harder for sweat to evaporate, and sweat is our primary method of cooling off. In hot and dry conditions, sweat can evaporate before we even know it was secreted, and that cools us off significantly. Also, Water can hold more heat than air, and transfers it better. You know this because 200 F water can cause serious damage, but people stick their bare arms into 400 F ovens all the time without even thinking about it (carefully avoiding the 400 F metal inside).

Comment: I've never heard this in Texas. Most of Texas is at least moderately humid.

Answer (score 20):

It's just a bit of gallows humor.

The remark is often said in real life to downplay someone else's complaint about heat. It's a casual remark and not something one would expect to hear in a life-and-death situation like the one in the movie -- so Hudson uses it as dark humor, its carefree normalcy contrasting with the extreme tension of the situation.

Comment: I also think that it's meant to be sarcastic because in that scene it's pretty clearly _very_ humid.